# BehaviorSubject keeps resetting to original value

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, behaviorsubject

I have an angular 2 project, in which I have a couple of components.
One of the components keeps track of a member (that is the aforementioned BehaviorSubject) using a subscription.

The BehaviorSubject's value is updated and pushed when a user clicks a button.

However, when subscribing, the only value ever pushed is the original value (that is 0).

The Navbar component is the subscriber, where in CountService the BehaviorSubject is declared.

My CountService:

```
@Injectable()
export class CountService {
    private count:number;
    public countObservable:BehaviorSubject<number>;
    public savedItems = { campaigns: [], news: [] };

    constructor (private http: Http) {
        this.count=0;
        this.countObservable = new BehaviorSubject<number>(this.count);
        this.countObservable.next(this.count);
    }

    keep(keepId: string, type: string){
        !!this.savedItems[type].length ?
            this.savedItems[type].find(i => i == keepId).length ?
            console.log('exist') : this.keepInSavedItems(keepId, type)
            this.keepInSavedItems(keepId, type);
    }

    keepInSavedItems(keepId, type){
        this.savedItems[type].push(keepId);
        this.count++;
        this.countObservable.next(this.count);
    }
}
```

My Navbar Component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  providers: [ CountService ]
})
export class NavigationbarComponent implements OnInit {
  count:number;

  constructor(public countService: CountService){
    this.count=0;
  }

  ngOnInit() : void {
    this.countService.countObservable.subscribe( count => this.count=count);
  }
}
```

Comment: how do you notify to push the value, i.e how does your click method look like?

Comment: I actually managed to solve it by making the observable static.

Answer (score 4):

You will get a new instance of `CountService` for every `NavigationbarComponent` when you provide the service in the component. 
If the component is added by the router, each route change might destroy and recreate the component and the service.

If you instead provide the service only in `@NgModule()` (only non-lazy-loaded modules), then there will only be one single instance for your whole application.

Comment: Did it, now the count does update but the values arent pushed with

    countObservable.next(this.count)

Answer (score 4):

Probably, that is happening because of **`providers`** array used in individual components.

remove **`provides:[CountService]`** from individual components and declare it in **`rootcomponent's @NgModule`**